# how to debug long running python commands in Azure Databricks notebook?

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/graph/tutorial-azure-databricks-hindex

I have obtained access to the Microsoft Academic Graph data set and want to issue some basic pySpark code against it, precisely per the tutorial.

For example, this code:

```
# Get affiliations
Affiliations = MAG.getDataframe('Affiliations')
Affiliations = Affiliations.select(Affiliations.AffiliationId, Affiliations.DisplayName)
Affiliations.show(3)
```

When I run the code with 'Shift + Enter', it goes into a state of 'Running command' - and never seems to finish, even after half an hour. I have inserted a screen shot of this and attached to my post.

I have run these commands individually, and it's the last one (`Affiliations.show(3)`) that causes the slowness.

For example, when I run the command (`Affiliations = MAG.getDataframe('Affiliations')`) by itself, I actually get a result:

```
AffiliationId:long
Rank:integer
NormalizedName:string
DisplayName:string
GridId:string
OfficialPage:string
WikiPage:string
PaperCount:long
CitationCount:long
Latitude:float
Longitude:float
CreatedDate:date
```

Question: how can I debug this to find out what's causing the slowness?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging a distributed application is still challenging in the notebook environment. Even though the web UI has the necessary information, there is a gap between web UIs and the development environment: it’s usually difficult to locate information in the web UI that is relevant to the code you are investigating; and there is no easy way to find historical runtime information.

[image]

**Understanding how to debug with the Databricks Spark UI:**

The Spark UI contains a wealth of information you can use for debugging your Spark jobs. There are a bunch of great visualizations, and we have a blog post here about those features.

[image]

For more details, click on Jobx View (Stages):

[image]

**Reference:** [Tips to Debug Apache Spark UI with Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/10/18/7-tips-to-debug-apache-spark-code-faster-with-databricks.html)

Hope this helps.